Multiple Active Chrome Profile freezes
If I open a single Chrome profile it works fine. But if I open additional Chrome profiles, then only the additional Chrome profile lags too much, and the main Chrome profile and all the other applications works fine.
I had this issue in ubuntu 22 and it still exists in ubuntu 24 as well.
I have noticed this issue in one of my colleagues system with same ubuntu version as well

Ubuntu version 22 and 24 are versions numbers for Ubuntu Core. If you are not using Ubuntu Core please edit the question and give the real version info. As for the Chrome question best to ask Chrome support on that, not an OS issue.
